# MIPS User input integers into array then printing them out

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, spim

Hello I have been practicing writing assembly language and I have been working on this seemingly simple code. I want to prompt the user for input then i want to take that input and put it into an array. Then i want to print out the array. I know I can just print them out without putting them in an array but this is just for my practice. Something is just not right though it wont print them back out.

```
    .data
array:  .space 400
prompt: .asciiz "Enter an integer (0 to quit) :"
text:   .asciiz "After sorting, the list of integers is:"
   .text
   .globl main
main:
    la $a1, array

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall

    sw $v0, 0($a1)
    addiu $a1, $a1, 4

    beqz $v0, sort
    j main

sort:
    la $a1, $array

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, text
    syscall

loop:
    lw $t0, 0($a1)
    addiu $a1, $a1, 4

    beqz $t0, done

    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t0
    syscall

    j loop

done:
```

please help me with what i am doing wrong. Oh and the zero is kind of the sentinal value when i hit a zero that means its the end of the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that branch and jump instructions on MIPS have delay slots. That is, the instruction directly following a branch or jump instruction is always executed.
It's possible that your assembler (gas?) is taking care of this for you by inserting `NOPs` or re-ordering instructions. You could find out by disassembling the binary with objdump. If the assembler *doesn't* fix this for you, the easiest way to fix it by yourself is to insert a `NOP` after each branch/jump.

The other thing that stands out is that you always reload `$a1` with the address of `array` before you read a new number. This means that every number you read will be stored at `array[0]`, including the terminating 0. So your print loop will find 0 as the first value in the array and exit immediately.
You could fix that by changing the code to something like this:

```
main:
la $a1, array
read_numbers:
  # Rest of code omitted for brevity...
  beqz $v0, sort
  j read_numbers
```

Comment: thanks! it was the simple mistake of loading the address in the loop. I didn't even realize that I was doing that. I appreciate it.